# Compiling and running using external jar files

Tags: java, command-prompt

I am able to compile the program `SendEmail.java`, but I can't figure out why isn't it running. Here is the program:

```
C:\6sem>javac -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\javamail-1.4.7\mail.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\javamail-1.4.7\activation.jar" SendEmail.java

C:\6sem>java -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\javamail-1.4.7\mail.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\javamail-1.4.7\activation.jar" SendEmail
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class SendEmail

Kindly help on how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifiy the full name of the class with the package name. This looks like the following example:

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\javamail-1.4.7\mail.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\javamail-1.4.7\activation.jar" com.company.dummy.SendEmail
```

Comment: can you please specify what is com.company.dummy ?

Comment: It is the package of your class. It's defined on top of the .java file (`package com.company.dummy;`).

Comment: @Rene still not working ? how to fix this problem ..kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the classPath issue.

Probably SendMail exists in two or more places, but in different Packages

Try this:-

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\javamail-1.4.7\mail.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\javamail-1.4.7\activation.jar" your.actual.class.is.here.SendEmail
```